# android google maps v2 get last know location and always start with network provider

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, maps, location

This Google Maps v2 api confuses me quite a bit. I have implemented it now in some way i would like to use it. I just have two small problems that i don't know how to go about.

Sometimes I don't get a location when i start the app with gps enabled or it takes way too long to get one.

So I would like it to always load with the internet location provider first to have a very fast location fix as well as always using the getlastknownlocation() first. Cant figure out how to go about it.

Here my code:

```
public class MapViewMain extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener, LocationSource
{

private GoogleMap mMap;

private OnLocationChangedListener mListener;
private LocationManager locationManager;

final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.mapviewmain);

   //start power button service

    Intent intent=new Intent("com.epicelements.spotnsave.START_SERVICE");  
    this.startService(intent);

    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

    if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Service not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       int requestCode = 10;
       Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
       dialog.show();

    }else { // Google Play Services are available



    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if(locationManager != null)
        {
            boolean gpsIsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            boolean networkIsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!gpsIsEnabled) {
          //    Toast.makeText(this, "GPS signal not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                PopIt("No GPS found", "Would you like to go to the settings to activate it?");                   
            }
            if(gpsIsEnabled)
            {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000L, 10F, this);
            }
            else if(networkIsEnabled)
            {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000L, 10F, this);
            }
            else
            {
                //Show an error dialog that GPS is disabled...
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Show some generic error dialog because something must have gone wrong with location manager.
        }

    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

}
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    if(locationManager != null)
    {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();




   locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
   locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);



   if(mListener != null){


   }


    setUpMapIfNeeded();


    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); // Enable the my-location layer 

    if(locationManager != null)
    {



        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); // Enable the my-location layer 

        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

    }


}


private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) 
    {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.



        if (mMap != null) 
        {
            setUpMap();
        }

        //This is how you register the LocationSource
        mMap.setLocationSource(this);  
    }
}

/**
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera.
 * <p>
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
 */
private void setUpMap()  
{
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    mMap.setPadding(0,60,0,150);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria(); criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);


    }




@Override
public void activate(OnLocationChangedListener listener) 
{
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
public void deactivate() 
{
    mListener = null;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{
    if( mListener != null )
    {
        mListener.onLocationChanged( location );

        double lat =  location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();


        LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(lat, lng);

        //save coordinate

        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
        Editor editor = pref.edit();

        editor.putFloat("lat", (float) location.getLatitude());
        editor.putFloat("lng", (float) location.getLongitude());
        editor.putFloat("accuracy", (float) location.getAccuracy());
        editor.commit();


        //marker stuff


        mMap.clear();

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions() 
                .position(coordinate) 
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker))); 

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 16));


    }
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//    Toast.makeText(this, "provider disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//    Toast.makeText(this, "provider enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
{
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 //     Toast.makeText(this, "status changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

// Alarm Dialog if GPS not enabled    

public void PopIt( String title, String message ){

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle( title )
    .setMessage( message )
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            //do stuff onclick of YES
            //AlertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            //do stuff onclick of CANCEL
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }).show();
}



}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use LocationClient for your purpose its give LastLocation very fast.

first declare class variable

```
private LocationClient client;
```

after in onCreate

```
try {
                if (map == null) {
                    MapsInitializer.initialize(this);
                    client = new LocationClient(this, new ConnectionCallbacks() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDisconnected() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            Toast.makeText(MotoFreightHomeMapMainActivity.this,
                                    "onConnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Location currentLocation = client.getLastLocation();
                            if (currentLocation != null) {
                                                     //do you stuff here
                            }

                        }
                    }, new OnConnectionFailedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
                    client.connect();

                }

            } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                // TODO handle this situation
                etMap.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                btnEditLocation.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please install Google Play Library",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

see full code here

http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: when you open first time map that service call connected method after you getting location you do not need this. you can use your listener code.

Comment: Thank you, but i still can't quite follow. Would you mind giving me an example with my code in full please if possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a sample and tutorial from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html).

Comment: thank you, but i would rather have a suggestion what to alter inside of my current code.

Comment: I was using the same code with you but this way is much more accurate and easy to implement. Sure it's up to you.

Comment: BoranA, thank you,  but for some reason i can not get that example working in my eclipse environment after download.

Comment: edit: got it working but i never get a location when gps is off. i need an immediate location from network provider or internet.

Comment: It's interesting cause my test phone has no sim card and gps is off but it can still locate correctly. There can be a problem with google services, updating google play services may help. Are you trying with sample application?